# negative z-index disappears under background

Tags: html, css, background, z-index, css-position

I'm trying to implement a div, that looks like a tall and narrow page, like a notebook paper.

I have my content in `<div id='centerframe'/>` and I thought that a good solution was to use an absolute positioned div for the "paper".

So I wrote the css rules as follows:

```
div#center_background
{
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:130px;
    width:900px;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}
```

However, when I add a background image to body, it disappears under the background. I tried setting a positive z-index, than it renders on top of everything in the page, like centerframe, topbar etc. See the picture:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

A solution could be setting z-index for all the elements, which I really don't want to do, since I want to use `position:absolute;`'s as little as possible.

So how can I define this kind of background div without changing other elements' positions and z-indices?

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AuWrE/), but it runs as expected. The strange thing in my real code is, when I load the page, the `center_background` div appears on top of background of body for a glance, then it disappears.
I don't change anything with JavaScript.

Comment: won't the background-image of the body always be behind everything else - the body is the bottom element (apart from html), please could you post more css and html or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: i was expecting that too. ok, ill make a fiddle in a few minutes.

Comment: Okay , i see , you are abusing absolute positionning here. Instead of doing z-index-1, do z-index:1 for header and z-index:0; for center_bg. At least it will give a hint to understand how z-index can be used. Cheers

Comment: so increasing all z-index, so that they all become positive, will solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i see your picture, i think that absolute positioning is unnecessary.
You could use fixed for the header, and let main content slides under it :
http://jsfiddle.net/jgYXr/

```
body {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/10);
}
nav {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    line-height:3em;
    background:tomato;
    box-shadow:0 0 1em 0.5em;
    text-align:right;
}
a {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 0.5em;
    padding:0 0.25em;
}
main {
    width:80%;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    box-shadow:0 0 1em 0.3em;
    margin:2em auto;
    min-height:800px;
}
```

```
<nav> 
  <a href="#">Nav link</a>
  <a href="#">Nav link</a>
  <a href="#">Nav link</a>
</nav>
<main>
</main>
```

Search for position: fixed and how to size an element in absolute or fixed via coordinates. See as well to set height of 1 element that has only 1 line of text.

Comment: position:fixed for the header is a great idea. But still does not solve my problem. Still the center_background is under the background of body..

Comment: wow, sorry I didn't read your code well. I applied that <main/> and it works great. and how did you center that? can you please explain what "auto" in "margin:2em auto;" does? Thanks !

Comment: margin: 3em auto; tells : 1st value: how far distance from bottom and top it must keep. 2nd value: Auto, for horizontal only, will balance on each side same distance from sides of parent container if it is smaller. for vertical margin, auto turns to have 0 for value.

Comment: oh i see it. Thank you very much! I'm accepting your answer as the correct one. But thanks to everybody !

Answer (score 2):

I came across this in my own code a few days back, and setting containing elements to `position: relative` solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks! But in my case, the containing element is body, and it didnt help to set position:relavite on body..

Answer (score 0):

put the z-index value in high range

```
  div#center_background
    {
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:130px;
    width:900px;
    height:100%;
    }
```

Comment: but that causes it to appear on top of everything, which I don't want.

Comment: maybe if you produced the code you are trying, we woukd tell you where it goes wrong

Comment: Ya fine Mr.Cengiz Frostclaw. Which error came while using that script?